# gnu c on_exit - segmentation fault

Tags: c, termination

Out of curiosity I am trying to get the libc on_exit function to work, but I have run into a problem with a segmentation fault. The difficulty I am having is finding an explanation of the proper use of this function. The function is defined in glibc as:

Function: int on_exit (void (*function)(int status, void *arg), void *arg)
This function is a somewhat more powerful variant of atexit. It accepts two arguments, a function and an arbitrary pointer arg. At normal program termination, the function is called with two arguments: the status value passed to exit, and the arg.

I created a small test, and I cannot find where the segmentation fault is generated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *
exitfn (int stat, void *arg) {
  printf ("exitfn has been run with status %d and *arg %s\n", stat, (char *)arg);
  return NULL;
}

int
main (void)
{
  static char *somearg="exit_argument";
  int exit_status = 1;

  on_exit (exitfn (exit_status, somearg), somearg);
  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compiled with:  gcc -Wall -o fn_on_exit fnc-on_exit.c

The result is:

```
$ ./fn_on_exit
exitfn has been run with status 1 and *arg exit_argument
Segmentation fault
```

Admittedly, this is probably readily apparent for seasoned coders, but I am not seeing it. What is the proper setup for use of the on_exit function and why in this case is a segmentation fault generated?

Comment: Portability node: `atexit` is Standard C; `on_exit` is *ad hoc* and not part of any standard, as far as I can see.

Comment: Correct, GNU libc specifies on_exit is included in the GNU C library only for compatibility for SunOS, and may not be supported by other implementations. However, being there, it does provide a mechanism for conditional termination/cleanup based on 'int status' or 'void *arg' if that is something needed in a particular piece of code. Presumably that is the reason for it's mention as a more robust alternative to atexit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line of code

```
  on_exit (exitfn (exit_status, somearg), somearg);
```

Should be

```
  on_exit (exitfn, somearg);
```

As you do not want to call the `exitfn` at this stage (that returns NULL!)

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was a forest-for-the-trees issue. The modifications required were: to make it 'void exitfn' instead of 'void * exitfn' and then use on_exit as you specified 'on_exit (exitfn, somearg)'

Comment: Additionally, changing exitfn from 'void *' to 'void' requires removal of 'return NULL'; as well.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  I did not wish to rub salt into the wounds

Comment: no salt, I really appreciate the help. I had read the glibc definition of on_exit use -- literally, and was stumped. Seeing the solution made immediate sense, but left to my own devices, it would have taken a really long time to get there. Thank you!

Comment: @EdHeal how to pass several arguments to `on_exit`?

Comment: Put them in a `struct` and use a pointer to this `struct` as `somearg`